# meaning of data members in sched_rt_entity

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

The following is the code for the entity class for RT policy in linux scheduling.

```
struct sched_rt_entity {
     struct list_head run_list;
     unsigned long timeout;
     unsigned int time_slice;

     struct sched_rt_entity *back;
     #ifdef CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED
     struct sched_rt_entity  *parent;
     /* rq on which this entity is (to be) queued: */
     struct rt_rq            *rt_rq;
     /* rq "owned" by this entity/group: */
     struct rt_rq            *my_q;
     #endif
};
```

What is data member `back` required when the list is already implemented.

I also do not understand how the group scheduling policy is implemented, particularly why there is a need of `my_rq` and `rt_rq` and who will `parent` point to.

Also what is the meaning of `timeout` data member.

**P.S.:**
I have lots and lots of such question, Can anyone suggest a good read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using group scheduling, there is not a single queue, but a tree of groups and their queues. For example, when two users have a scheduling group each, the overall group/queue might allocate 50 % CPU to each user's group, while all the users' programs are in their group's queue and compete for that 50 %.
For a more detailed explanation of how the multiple queues work, see [CFS group scheduling](http://lwn.net/Articles/240474/).

`parent` points to the entity one level up in the tree; `rt_rq` is the queue on which this entity runs, while `my_q` is the queue on which this entity's children run.

The `back` field is used as temporary storage in the `dequeue_rt_stack()` function to implement a stack, where we have a pointer to the lowest entity, but want to remove them beginning from the top-level one.

`timeout` is increased by the watchdog timer and used to check that the task does not hog the CPU for longer than `RLIMIT_RTTIME`.

---

There are no books about recent kernel changes.
*Use the source, Luke.*

Comment: I understand this but it would be great if you can offer some more insight on why such a structure is used as thee explanation has given rise to a few more questions. More specifically, why there is a need of the queue in which the children are running.

Comment: Also another question because you have brought up `dequeue_rt_stack`, I do not understand that what if the pointer is not to the lowest entity, when the temporary assignment using back is going to take place we assign `rt_se->back=back` which means we are assigning it `null` without talking care about if that was in the middle of any list, in other words  what if some other entities are pointing to it(as they were a part of same group) and now only this entity and their parents would remain together.